# How to modify the limits of y axis of a stacked bar chart in polar coordinates using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have ploted a stacked bar chart with "position = stack" in polar coordinates.

```
ggplot(d, aes(Component, Freq, fill = Subtype2)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.03, 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous('Distribution', expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_nejm() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'IHC subtype')) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        plot.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.25),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 0.25),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image]

To add a space between the start and the end of y axis, I add `limits = c(0, 2000)` in `scale_y_continuous`.

```
ggplot(d, aes(Component, Freq, fill = Subtype2)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.03, 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous('Distribution', expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 2000)) +
  scale_fill_nejm() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'IHC subtype')) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        plot.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.25),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 0.25),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image]

Next, I want to plot a proportional bar chart in polar coordinates and I tried the code below:

```
ggplot(d, aes(Component, Freq, fill = Subtype2)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'fill', stat = 'identity') +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.03, 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous('Distribution', expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_nejm() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'IHC subtype')) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        plot.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.25),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 0.25),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image]

I want to add a space between the start and the end of y axis as well with the following code but the output was weird with warning message.

```
ggplot(d, aes(Component, Freq, fill = Subtype2)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'fill', stat = 'identity') +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.03, 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous('Distribution', expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_fill_nejm() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'IHC subtype')) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        plot.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.25),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 0.25),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10))
Warning message:
Removed 6 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

[image]

**data**

```
structure(list(Component = structure(c(11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 11L, 
10L, 9L, 8L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 11L, 10L, 9L), .Label = c("10", 
"9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "0"), class = "factor"), 
    Subtype2 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("HR+/HER2-", "HR+/HER2+", 
    "HR-/HER2+", "TNBC"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(12L, 433L, 
    67L, 66L, 87L, 461L, 287L, 84L, 17L, 332L, 60L, 32L, 44L, 
    278L, 159L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 34L, 35L, 36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Using `position = "fill"` rescales the data such that the maximum of the stacked bars is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bit trickier than I imagined. The y-scale seems to want to throw away values that exceed the limits before the position is calculated. To prevent this, you can use `scales::oob_keep()` to retain these values. Simplified example below.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# d <- structure(...) # taken from question, omitted for brevity

ggplot(d, aes(Component, Freq, fill = Subtype2)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.1), oob = scales::oob_keep) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]